# DB2 connect SQL1042C error

Tags: db2

When I give DB2 CONNECT command I get the error saying "SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred". The most weird thing is this issue is intermittant.

```
sqlcode: -1042; 
sqlstate: 58004; 
DB2 connect command: connect to dbname user db2admin using password;
```

My DB2 version is: DB2/NT64 9.5.0

Answer (score 2):

There are a few directions in the [Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01042c.html) on how you might be able to fix this error, one of which involves calling IBM for support.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
db2 "? sql-1042"
```

for more information.
On the other hand, if you just installed new db2 software code, try to use

```
db2iupdt instance_name
```

to update db2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

You might find additional information in the file db2diag.log, which is located in a place like /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/db2diag.log . Or you can use the command db2diag with an option like db2diag -lastrecords 100

Answer (score 0):

Actually SQL1042C can be happened with many reasons.
It's better to check db2diag.log first as it will give the idea about what this may be about.

And if that happens with DB activation by first connect,

```
db2stop
db2diag -A
db2start
db2 connect to dbname user db2admin using password
=> SQL1042C
```

Check what's recorded on new db2diag.log.

As William mentioned previously, 'db2iupdt' is the good attempt when you have no idea right away.

Answer (score 0):

run db2iupdt, 
looks like issues with binaries ,
let me know , when you got this error.
if possible  upload following command output
db2diag -g 'level=Critical'